# Dictionary inside a list. Return the dictionary name

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm making my first project a tic tac toe game. I have the following:

```
the_board = {'1 3': ' ' , '2 3': ' ' , '3 3': ' ' ,
            '1 2': ' ' , '2 2': ' ' , '3 2': ' ' ,
            '1 1': ' ' , '2 1': ' ' , '3 1': ' ' }
        
wins = [[the_board['1 3'],the_board['2 3'],the_board['3 3']],
            [the_board['1 2'],the_board['2 2'],the_board['3 2']],
            [the_board['1 1'],the_board['2 1'],the_board['3 1']],
            [the_board['1 3'],the_board['1 2'],the_board['1 1']],
            [the_board['2 3'],the_board['2 2'],the_board['2 1']],
            [the_board['3 3'],the_board['3 2'],the_board['3 1']],            
            [the_board['1 3'],the_board['2 2'],the_board['3 1']],
            [the_board['1 1'],the_board['2 2'],the_board['3 3']]]
```

Is there any way that when I type `wins[0][0]`, it prints `"the_board['1 3']"`? Can I then assign an `"X"` to `the_board['1 3']`?

Thanks

Comment: No, the list has no idea what expression you used to put the objects in the list when it was initialized in the list literal. Almost certainly, there is a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do, maybe elaborate on that because this seems like the [X-Y problem](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) Note, there *is no dictionary inside your list*.

Comment: Why don't you use tuples as keys, i.e. `(1, 3)` instead of `"1 3"`?